# Unable to save ListBox Items in sorted order

Tags: asp.net, sorting, webforms, listbox

In my .NET web forms page, I have a ListBox and some jQuery that allows me to sort the items.  I select several items and then loop over them to save to my database.  I want to save the order the items are sorted in, however, I am unable to get it to work.  My codebehind is shown:

```
    protected void session_DetailsView_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        panel_SqlDataSource.Delete();
        ListBox panel_ListBox = session_DetailsView.FindControl("panel_ListBox") as ListBox;
        int so = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < panel_ListBox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (panel_ListBox.Items[i].Selected == true)
            {
                so++;
                panel_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters["presenterID"].DefaultValue = panel_ListBox.Items[i].Value;
                panel_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters["sortOrder"].DefaultValue = so.ToString();
                panel_SqlDataSource.Insert();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Forget the database for the moment, you should just Trace the output to figure out if what you're expecting to happening is happening. Then worry about the database.

Comment: Also paste your jQuery code...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so your order is being changed on the client side probably won't effect the order that it is on the server as that will probably be defined somewhere in the viewstate. Your controls will just come back as they were displayed originally. You need to somehow keep a track of the order of things - pull it out of the form variables or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

ASP .Net is not aware of the fact the items in the ListBox have been changed on the client side. Probably you are using jQuery.sortable method to sort the listbox items. You need to call sortable with "serialize" option and save the value into a hidden field. When you post the form you read that value of that hidden field and save the new order in the database.

So for sample if the objects with ids 1, 2, 3 have the new order 2, 3, 1 then create update/insert methods like this:

```
update tbl set sortOrder = 1 where presenterId = 2
update tbl set sortOrder = 2 where presenterId = 3
update tbl set sortOrder = 3 where presenterId = 1
```